# change default date format laravel sql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to change date out put from following SELECT query to DD/MM/YYY format . pls advice.

this is what I tried so far

```
  ->select('time_sheets.progress',DATE_FORMAT('time_sheets.date', "%d/%l/%Y") ,'role_users.role_id','roles.role_name')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `->select` you can use `selectRaw` to allow raw SQL query so you can use:

```
->selectRaw('time_sheets.progress, DATE_FORMAT(time_sheets.date, "%d/%l/%Y"), role_users.role_id, roles.role_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->select('time_sheets.progress',\DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(p.created_at,\'%d-%m-%Y\') as data')), role_users.role_id, roles.role_name');
```

Hope to help someone else !

Answer (score 0):

```
->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(column_name), "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s") as cstime_value'))
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.